# How to response in JSON below String? using PHP Webservice

Tags: php, arrays, json, web-services

Input str = "102_254,102_274,102_232,104_225,104_226,103_233,103_229,101_316,101_244,101_249,101_250"

Here Input is "102_254" means "Menuid_Submenuid"

- 102 is menuId
- 254 is subMenuId

Table name is :

- SubMenuTable

Table Fields is:

- menuid
- submenuid
- item

I want to select item name from "SubMenuTable" table and response it to JSON Format

Output will be separate like this:

- 102

  - 254
  - 274
  - 232
- 104

  - 225
  - 226
- 103

  - 233
  - 229
- 101

  - 316
  - 244
  - 249
  - 250

I want to output in JSON Formate like this:

{"0":{"101":{"0":{"menuid":"101","submenuid":"316","item":"ItemName1"},"1":{"menuid":"101","submenuid":"244","item":"ItemName2"},"2":{"menuid":"101","submenuid":"249","item":"ItemName3"},"3":{"menuid":"101","submenuid":"250","item":"ItemName4"}},"102":{"0":{"menuid":"102","submenuid":"254","item":"ItemName1"},"1":{"menuid":"102","submenuid":"274","item":"ItemName2"},"2":{"menuid":"102","submenuid":"232","item":"ItemName3"}},"103":{"0":{"menuid":"103","submenuid":"233","item":"ItemName1"},"1":{"menuid":"103","submenuid":"229","item":"ItemName2"}},"104":{"0":{"menuid":"104","submenuid":"225","item":"ItemName1"},"1":{"menuid":"104","submenuid":"226","item":"ItemName2"}}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reformatting prototype just need to prepend items and encode each sub-array:

```
$sInput = '102_254,102_274,102_232,104_225,104_226,103_233,103_229,101_316,101_244,101_249,101_250';
$aInput = explode( ',', $sInput );
$iCountInputs = count( $aInput );
for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountInputs; ++$i )
{
    $aInner = explode( '_', $aInput[ $i ] );
    $aTmp[ $aInner[ 0 ] ][] = $aInner[ 1 ];
}
$sJson = json_encode( $aTmp );
var_dump( $aInput );
var_dump( $sJson );

$aAfter = json_decode( $sJson, 1 );
var_dump( $aAfter );
```